# Technical differences in creating object with private member

Tags: javascript

[Here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) I found a pattern of javascript module enabling private members of object. If I got it right, it can be written this way:

```
var myObject1 = (function(){
  var privateMember = 42;
  return {
    publicMember: function() {
      return privateMember;
    }
  }
})();
```

But there is more effective way:

```
var myObject2 = new function() {
  var privateMember = 42;
  this.publicMember = function() {
    return privateMember;
  }
}
```

Is there any difference between those two? Are there any other possibilities to implement private members?

This is the result from Chrome debugger:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the second way is "more effective"?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder less lines of code, less curly brackets. Effective from coder point of view. Does the browser share the opinion?

Comment: @ Jan: No, the browser doesn't care.

Comment: Those who voted to close: can you explain how this is non-constructive?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but as a Pythonista I normally prefix my private variables with a `_` and get back to solving actual problems :-).

Comment: @JanTuroň: I suspect the "non-constructive" close votes are because of the word "proper" (originally) and now "best" in the title. People see "proper" or "best" and they think "opinion" and questions with answers based in opinion are non-constructive. Your actual *question*, if someone bothers to read it, is clearly *not* a question about opinions but about what the technical differences are between the two forms. But there we are. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. I changed the title once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's only a couple of real technical differences between those two (pointed out by Bergi in the comments). The differences aren't likely to matter unless you're doing thousands and thousands of these. There's a *style* difference, which is subjective, but the technical differences are small. See the breakdown below for the gory details.

At a high level, both forms create a new object, they both rely on a closure for the private member. The second way uses a bit more memory, because the function can't be garbage-collected after use, whereas in the first one, it can be. Similarly, the object created to be the function's `prototype` property is reclaimable in the first version, but not the second. The second way may also be less clear to some than the first (witness the questions below from @djechlin), not least because of the implicit return value, but that's a style point.

Re your second question:

> Are there any other possibilities to implement private members?

For one-off objects like yours, the way you're doing it is probably best (either form, really). But right now, there's *sort of* another way, and as of ES.Next (the next version of ECMAScript), there's a new truly private way. In both cases, though, it's more useful for when you're doing classes of objects rather than one-offs.

More in [this entry on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2013/05/private-properties-in-es6-and-es3-and.html) (which also talks about the stuff coming with ES.Next), but I'll go into the most salient details here.

The typical pattern for private members in classes of objects looks something like this:

```
function Foo(toBePrivate) {
    var privateMember = toBePrivate;

    this.method1 = function() {
        // ...do something with the truly private `privateMember`
    };
}
Foo.prototype.method2 = function() {
    // ...doesn't have access to the truly private `privateMember`
};

var f = new Foo("private stuff");
// f.method1() can use the private data
// f.method2() cannot
```

The problem with it is that each and every object created via `new Foo` gets its **own** `method1` function. We don't get the reuse we get with `method2`, where there's only *one* of them shared by all objects created by `new Foo`. (This isn't necessarily a big deal with modern engines, which are able to reuse the *code* of `method1` even though a new `method1` *object* is created for each `Foo` object. But there are some development patterns that dynamically change the prototype, which are obviously unable to act on `method1` above.)

Here's the nearly-private pattern we can do today:

```
var Foo = (function() {
    // Create a private name object for our private property
    var privateKey = makeRandomString();

    // Our constructor    
    function Foo(toBePrivate) {
        this[privateKey] = toBePrivate;
    }

    // Define the private property so it's non-enumerable
    Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, privateKey, {
        writable: true
    });

    // Methods shared by all Foo instances
    Foo.prototype.method1 = function() {
        // ...use this[privateKey] here...
    };
    Foo.prototype.method2 = function() {
        // ...use this[privateKey] here...
    };

    return Foo;
})();

var f = new Foo("private stuff");
// f.method1() can use the private data
// f.method2() can too!
// Both `method1` and `method2` are *reused* by all `Foo` objects
```

...where `makeRandomString` does exactly that, it gives us a new random string every time we call it.

The property we create is not private, but it's really obscure. It doesn't show up in `for-in` loops (because the property we created is non-enumerable) and its name changes every time the code runs. So any code attempting to use the private data must first figure out the property name, which is a non-trivial exercise as that code can't get a list of the non-enumerable property names of the object. Naturally, though, one glance at the object in a debugger shows you the property and its value. The property is *really obscure*, but not quite truly private.

This pattern is improved markedly by the stuff coming in ES.Next, the next version of ECMAScript. We'll get [private name objects](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aprivate_name_objects), which are useful on their own and are also used by the [the new classses](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aclasses).

Here's how private names apply to the above:

```
// **ES.Next, not yet available in the wild**
import Name from "@name";
var Foo = (function() {
    // Create a private name object for our private property
    var privateKey = new Name();

    function Foo(toBePrivate) {
        this[privateKey] = toBePrivate;
    }
    Foo.prototype.method1 = function() {
        // ...use this[privateKey] here...
    };
    Foo.prototype.method2 = function() {
        // ...use this[privateKey] here...
    };

    return Foo;
})();

var f = new Foo("private stuff");
// f.method1() can use the private data
// f.method2() can too!
// Both `method1` and `method2` are *reused* by all `Foo` objects
```

Properties created with private name objects never show up in `for-in` enumerations **at all**, and their names are not strings. Code **cannot** access a property whose name is a private name object without having *that specific name object*. Since the `privateKey` variable above is completely private to the `Foo` class, no other code can use that property. It's completely private. Naturally, these will show up in debuggers, but then, nothing is private from debuggers.

---

@djechlin asked for a breakdown of exactly how each of your forms for a private member work, and it helps us understand the difference between them that Bergi highlighted:

### Your first example:

```
var myObject1 = (function(){
  var privateMember = 42;
  return {
    publicMember: function() {
      return privateMember;
    }
  }
})();
```

*(This list leaves out a few details that I don't think are relevant.)*

1. A property called `myObject1` is created on the current variable binding object (which may be `window` if this is global) with the value `undefined`.
2. The function expression is evaluated:

   A) A `Function` object to be created.

   B) A blank object is created and assigned to the new function's `prototype` property.

   C) A `constructor` property is created on that object and given a reference to the function.

   D) A reference to the current variable binding object is stored on the function.
3. The function is called, creating (amongst other things) a variable binding object for the execution context of the call.
4. A property called `privateMember` is created and assigned to the variable binding object from Step 3.
5. The value 42 is assigned to the `privateMember` property of the VBO.
6. A blank object is created and given a prototype from `Object.prototype`.
7. The inner function expression is evaluated, a `Function` object created (with a blank object for its `prototype` property and a `constructor` property put on that object, and with a reference to the current variable binding object [the one from Step 3]).
8. That function is assigned to a property on the blank object from Step 5 as `publicMember`.
9. A reference to the object from Step 6 is returned from the main anonymous function.
10. That object reference is stored in the `myObject1` property created in Step 1.
11. The main anonymous function (from Step 2) has no outstanding references, and so can be reclaimed by GC; and so the object referenced by its `prototype` property can also be reclaimed by GC.

#### Your second example:

```
var myObject2 = new function() {
  var privateMember = 42;
  this.publicMember = function() {
    return privateMember;
  }
}
```

*(Again, some irrelevant details left out.)*

1. A property called `myObject2` is created on the current variable binding object (which may be `window` if this is global) with the value `undefined`.
2. The function expression is evaluated:

   A) A `Function` object to be created.

   B) A blank object is created and assigned to the new function's `prototype` property.

   C) A `constructor` property is created on that object and given a reference to the function.

   D) A reference to the current variable binding object is stored on the function.
3. A new, blank object is created and assigned its prototype from the anonymous function's `prototype` property.
4. The function is called with the object from Step 3 passed in as `this`, creating (amongst other things) a variable binding object for the execution context of the call.
5. A property called `privateMember` is created and assigned to the variable binding object from Step 4.
6. The value 42 is assigned to the `privateMember` property of the VBO.
7. The inner function expression is evaluated, a `Function` object created (with a blank object for its `prototype` property and a `constructor` property put on that object, and with a reference to the current variable binding object [the one from Step 4]).
8. That function is assigned to a property on the blank object from Step 5 as `publicMember`.
9. The function returns, and because it doesn't return an object, the result of the `new` expression is a reference to the object created in Step 3.
10. That object reference is stored in the `myObject2` property created in Step 1.
11. The main anonymous function (from Step 2) cannot be reclaimed by GC, because `myObject2`'s underlying prototype has a reference to it on the `constructor` property (and so both the function and the object assigned to its `prototype` property remain in memory).

You could release the function (but not the object assigned to its `prototype` property) by adding this line inside it:

```
delete this.constructor.prototype.constructor;
```

That removes the reference to the function from the object assigned to its `prototype` property. That object remains as `myObject2`'s underlying prototype, but it no longer refers back to the function, so the function is eligible for GC.

But at that point, we're well into obscurity land. :-)

### Conclusions

So they're very nearly the same, with the small difference that the main anonymous function and the object on its `prototype` property aren't eligible for GC. It would take thousands and thousands of these for that to matter in the real world.

(Side note: Some implementations may well defer some of the steps of creating a function — such as creating a blank object for its `prototype` property and setting its `constructor` — until/unless that `prototype` property is used, since of course in the *vast* majority of cases, it's never used, because the vast majority of functions are never used as constructor functions. So your first form may be *a little tiny teeny bit* more efficient because it can skip those steps. It's a difference that is unlikely to matter unless you're doing thousands of these.)

---

FWIW, the first can also be written like this, if your concern is the number of lines, number of parentheses, or not liking the object literal, etc.:

```
var myObject1 = function(){
  var obj = {};
  var privateMember = 42;
  obj.publicMember = function() {
    return privateMember;
  };
  return obj;
}();
```

As a matter of *style*, I prefer the explicit return, but that's a matter of style.

Comment: For more ignorant readers such as myself, would you mind elaborating on how this works?  In particular I don't know what `new function()` does, I'm used to seeing `new Ctor()`.

Comment: @djechlin: The `new function() { ... };` basically *is* `new Ctor();`. What happens is that the anonymous function is called as a constructor function, so a new object is created and passed to the function as `this`, and the result of calling the function is that new object because the function doesn't return something else. The only real difference is that the constructor function is defined inline and so can't be reused.

Comment: so this use of `new` also has the effect of *calling* the function in addition to the usual effect of creating new object and binding `this` to it?

Comment: @djechlin: Yes, just like `new Ctor();` does.

Comment: but with `new function() { ... }` it's not necessary to *call* it at the end of it - so `var f = new function() {...}();` would then call the returned new object as a function which throws error I think, since objects that do not inherit from `Function` cannot be called.  (Unless the anon function explicitly returns a function instead of letting the return value be `this`).  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @djechlin: Exactly right. (Which is why there's no `()` at the end of the OP's second example.)

Comment: Thanks.  I'd suggest editing this info into answer so we can clean up the comments.

Comment: It's not only a matter of style, there is a technical difference! The one with new has a serious flaw, as the IECFE is not anonymous and cannot be garbage-collected: `var myObject3 = new myObject2.constructor();`!

Comment: @Bergi: Can you please explain what is IECFE and why it can not be garbage-collected?

Comment: @JanTuroň: I've updated the answer to cover it. I don't know what IECFE stands for, but my guess would be "Inline-Executed Constructor Function Expression."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: almost. Derived from [I(I|E)FE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), it meant "*immediately executed constructor function expression*" :-)

Comment: @JanTuroň: I realized I never answered your question about other ways to do private members, so I've added a (fairly long!) discussion of that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your answer. It could be a book with table of contents. Your patience will be worth it: it will take me some time to read it thoroughly, I'm just in the process of understanding how Javascript works behind the scenes.

Comment: @JanTuroň: You're welcome! Yeah, it *is* a bit long. BTW, if you're interested, I [write about JavaScript](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search/label/javascript) from time to time on [my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/)...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any difference between those two?

One major difference is that in the second case using *new*, the returned object has an additional object on it's `[[Prototype]]` chain that is the public prototype of the constructor function expression. That object can be accessed in some browsers using `__proto__`.

Also, `myObject1.constructor` is the built–in Object function, while `myObject2.constructor` is the function created by the function expression.

> Are there any other possibilities to implement private members?

I suppose you could use the object's (otherwise useless) `__proto__` object, but that's more obfuscation than privacy (and not available in some browsers):

```
var foo = new function() {

  this.__proto__.privateMember = 42;

  this.publicMember = function() {
    return this.__proto__.privateMember;
  }
};

alert(foo.publicMember());
```

Pretty ugly really.

Closures have been used to emulate private members in javascript for quite some time (more than 10 years at least) but there hasn't been any real pressure to include them in ECMA-262 (as far as I'm aware). I suppose that indicates that private members are handy, but not critical to implement functionality required for the type of host environment scripting that javascript is typically used for.

#### Edit

As Bergi says, the ES5 [*Object.getPrototypeOf*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2) method should be used in stead of the (non standard) [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property. My bad for no pointing that out initially.

Comment: see my updated answer: both objects seem to have `this.__proto__.constructor`; the `__proto__` is different since `function` prototype is different to object literal `{}` prototype, which is `Object`.

Comment: I updated my answer. The `__proto__.constructor` in both cases is Object, it's the returned object's constructor that is different.

Comment: I don't see why "private" members on the prototype were either private or obfuscating anything (other then the creation code). You still can get and set `foo.privateMember`

Comment: Please use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead of `__proto__` so that it can be accessed in **all** browsers!

Comment: @Bergi—yes, they're not "private" at all, I was just looking for alternatives to a closure. Obfuscated because it's a bit weird to use the `[[Prototype]]` that way. Certainly not suggesting it should be done. *getPrototypeOf* is ES5 so still not in all browsers in use (but a better idea than `__proto__`).

Comment: *"Closures have been used to emulate private members in javascript for quite some time (more than 10 years at least) but there hasn't been any real pressure to include them in ECMA-262"* **Wow** is that not true. It was very high on the list indeed, and they'll be in ES.Next, both [on their own](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:private_name_objects) and [as part of classes](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:classes).

Comment: @Bergi or RobG: not private? Both `myObject1.privateMember` and `myObject2.privateMember` returns undefined.

Comment: @JanTuroň: Bergi is pointing out that the "private" thing created by RobG (`this._proto_.privateMember`) is not remotely private. *Your* pattern absolutely creates a private member.

Comment: @JanTuroň—the properties are public on the `[[Prototype]]`, not the object itself. They could just as easily be on any other object, I just chose to use the otherwise useless object created by new *FunctionExpression*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—I qualified my statement. I don't see anyone asking for this stuff like they do with fixing *typeof*, *constructor*, etc. and the types of things fixed with strict mode. Adding more formal OO classes to javascript is a complete waste of time and misses the point, **IMHO**. It's been available in browsers with Java for ages, and we know how well that's going.

Comment: @RobG: The reasons Java failed in browsers are many and varied, and have nothing to do with having real classes and everything to do with the cluelessness of Sun and then Oracle in terms of making the experience smooth for the end user, the obstinance of Apple, and the Microsoft/Sun war. If you think people aren't asking for "real" classes in JavaScript, well, I don't think you're listening very well. ;-) But again: To say that there's no demand for real private members? C'mon... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—I think there are a lot of people coming from other languages who wish javascript was just like that language. Maybe there is a need for a language like javascript that is more like C# or C++ or Java or F# or whatever that favourite other language happens to be.  The next step will be to compile the code and download just the executable, all nicely sandboxed in the browser of course. Sounds familiar…

Comment: @RobG: :-) Well, I love JavaScript itself, but I still felt the need to create [`Lineage`](https://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) because today's JavaScript still makes inheritance (prototypical inheritance) a bit harder than it should be. ES5 was a great step forward on that, and I think ES6 will be as well. Re "compiling" JavaScript and downloading the "executable," with the Closure Compiler at full throttle, the future is now. :-) That output is every bit as obscure looking at decompiled Java bytecode. Anyway, good to see you as always. :-)