# How to make JavaScript objects more readable/navigable?

Tags: javascript, object, web-inspector

I'm creating an object with a bunch of nested objects. When working with the web inspector, I'm constantly having to reorient myself because all of these objects are simply called `Object`. A condensed version of my object tree looks like this:

```
v Object
    v fields: Array[3]
        v 0: Object
            v fields: Array[2]
                v 0: Object
                    name: 'name'
                    placeholder: 'name'
                    tag: 'input'
                    type: 'text'
                > 1: Object
            name: 'name'
            tag: 'fieldset'
        > 1: Object
        > 2: Object
    name: 'name'
```

This gets old fast. Is there any way to make this more readable/navigable? If so, is it efficient? Like this:

```
v form
    v fields: Array[3]
        v 0: fieldset
            v fields: Array[2]
                v 0: input
                     name: 'name'
                     placeholder: 'name'
                     tag: 'input'
                     type: 'text'
                > 1: textarea
            name: 'name'
            tag: 'fieldset'
        > 1: fieldset
        > 2: button
    name: 'name'
```

Or is this just something I'm going to have to deal with?

Comment: Do you mean you want a DOM tree instead?

Comment: Well, objects are `Object`s - afaik the inspector writes out the `.constructors` name. But I guess it doesn't make much sense to change your codebase just for easier debugging.

Comment: No, I'm making an object of a DOM tree to be manipulated server-side.

Comment: @Marcus: Then just inspect the `JSON.stringify(tree, null, 4)` which you're doing anyway to send it. Or, actually you better would serialize the DOM tree to XML instead of JSON :-)

Comment: You are in luck.Read this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835451/javascript-prototypes-objects-constructori-am-confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand all properties automatically and not read `Object` or `Array[l]` everywhere, a common technique is to log the prettyfied JSON representation. It also has the benefit of not changing in the console when your objects are mutated after being logged. You only should not do it with very large objects, and it's impossible on cyclic objects.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would prefer to read plain text, you can `console.log(JSON.stringify(your_object))`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a named function to create your objects:

```
  var a = {foo:"bar"};
  var b = new function myobj() {
    this.foo = "bar";
  }
  console.log(a,b); // Object, myobj
```

If you want reusable objects, you should use

```
  function myobj() {
    this.foo = "bar";
  }
  var objA = new myobj();
  var objB = new myobj();
  console.log(objA,objB); // myobj, myobj
```

If you want to dive deep into the differences, see [this very detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16553023/343721) of TJ Crowder to my question.

Comment: How (in)efficient is doing that?

Comment: @Marcus: Of course it's much less efficient than just using Object literals, but you also gain inheritance. I wouldn't recommend it on pure *data* objects, though, which are parsed from simple JSON strings for example.

Comment: @Bergi: As I studied the TJC answer, I would replace your *much* for *little*.

Comment: JSON it is for now, but this will come in handy later on. Thanks.

Comment: @JanTuroň: That answer is comparing efficiency of private-scoped variables with public properties - both created with a constructor. I meant that a constructor-less approach vs one with a function call